# Easiest way to transfer NFT (ERC-721) IN to safe?

Tags: nft, erc-721, gnosis-safe

What is the best way to transfer an NFT TO a Safe Vault?
Does a safe vault support ERC-721 transfers IN via SafeTransferFrom like a standard transfer through OpenSea?

Thanks for any guidance you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer your NFT easily to Safe. Just go to your metamask and go down to NFT's there, click transfer,, and enter the safe address . Your NFT will now be sent to your Safe.